# edit javascript on the fly

Tags: javascript, firebug, edit

I was curious how I might go about editing a variable on the fly, since whenever I try nothing happens. Take http://nyan.cat for example. I tried to edit the seconds variable, but nothing happened - why?

i used (in the JS console) `seconds = 9001; RET` and nothing happens....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because in http://nyan.cat/ the `seconds` variable is being set by the script repeatedly, based on the `startTime` Date object. In the specific case of http://nyan.cat/, to 'hack' the time, change the `startTime`.

Example: to increase your `seconds` by 1234567 seconds:

```
startTime = new Date(((+startTime/1000)-1234567)*1000);
```

Comment: it doesn't give the rasta cap or do anything special, unfortunately :(

Comment: That's because you need to pass through the 420th second, not skip over it. Setting `startTime` so `seconds` becomes something like 410 is good, or you can call `turnRasta` directly.

Answer (score 0):

What JS console are you using?In the firebug?

Here I tested it.

```
var seconds = 9001;

alert(seconds);
```

Comment: `seconds` will get changed back based on the `startTime` in http://nyan.cat/ almost instantly.